# Automated application call using Lync

Tags: sip, lync, ucma

I would like to build a notification application on server which will contact (telephone call) persons via our existing Lync server. I already build proof-of-concept using Lync Model API, but since that approach requires running Lync client I don't believe this is practical in my case. Am I mistaken or I should try UCMA? As I can tell UCMA doesn't require Lync client installed/running?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, you will need to create an application (or service) with UCMA. This application can authenticate itself with the Lync server, create an endpoint, and then is able to create conversations/calls/messages (amongst other thing). This does not require a lync client install on the server.

Here is an MSDN video on creating a "Hello World" UCMA example application: [UCMA Hello World - Send an Instant Message](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/UCMA-Hello-World-Send-an-Instant-Message). I know this is about IM and not an Audio call, but once you get the IM bit, making it create an audio call instead is trivial.